# Image (from url) loading again in other component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have two scenes in my app (react-navigation).

**Scene 1:** Flat List with an Image per row

**Scene 2:** Same Image with some more details

If I am navigating from Scene 1 to Scene 2 the component is always loading the Image again.

Why does the Image-component not use the Image from the cache? On other components (without navigating) the Cache is working. Cache-Control is set to max_age=2592000.

Comment: Did you try importing the image source in a separate file and then export it as a component?

Answer (score 0):

If the image(s) are static, you can import and export them from a single file:

```
export default class Images {
    static image1 = require("../public/images/image1.jpg");
    static image2 = require("../public/images/image2.jpg");
}
```

You can use a tool like https://github.com/wcandillon/react-native-static-images to script this for you.

Comment: Like mentioned in the title I am loading the images from a server, unfortunately.

Comment: I get the image urls on runtime because I am fetching them from an API.